# from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run a code using keras. The program uses `from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session` and i am getting the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/phili/Desktop/python-projects/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend'; 
'keras.backend' is not a package
```

I  am using python 3.7 Keras 2.4.3 and tensorflow 2.2.0

Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are importing it incorrectly.

The command to `import set_session`, for `Tensorflow 2.3` (latest version) is shown below:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session
```

Please find [this Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/f3861886b1e23e495f7d5c2f855bb946/so_63104255_set_session.ipynb) for working code.

Please refer this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/backend/set_session) for more information.